# Mumble doesn't bind to network address on boot, needs to be restarted (doesn't properly wait for network?)

Tags: debian, networking

I have a default, unchanged installation of the Mumble server on Debian Squeeze (package "mumble-server"). On a previous setup, starting the server (called murmurd) on boot using the default init scripts worked fine. On a new setup, that seems to me to be identical in every way, murmurd doesn't seem to bind to a network address on boot. No clients can thus connect until I restart the process after booting.

The logs are quite telling. On boot:

```
<W>2012-03-25 00:15:01.543 Murmur 1.2.2 (1.2.2-6+squeeze1) running on
X11: Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.4 (squeeze): Booting servers <W>2012-03-25
00:15:01.617 1 => Announcing server via bonjour <W>2012-03-25
00:15:01.650 1 => Not registering server as public
```

and no clients can connect. Using `service mumble-server restart` after boot, however, gives:

```
<W>2012-03-25 00:22:27.529 Murmur 1.2.2 (1.2.2-6+squeeze1) running on
X11: Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.4 (squeeze): Booting servers <W>2012-03-25
00:22:27.549 1 => Server listening on [::]:64738 <W>2012-03-25
00:22:27.559 1 => Announcing server via bonjour <W>2012-03-25
00:22:27.570 1 => Not registering server as public
```

Notice the third line.
It thus seems to me that the init script tries to start the daemon before the network is up and running. The `/etc/rc2.d/S19mumble-server` script that comes with the package says, though:

```
# Required-Start:       $network $local_fs $remote_fs dbus
```

The exact same setup works fine on a different machine (also running Debian Squeeze), so I'm beginning to suspect it has something to do with timing on boot, or some other nondeterministic factor.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is already two years old but recently I stumbled over the same problem on a machine running 'wheezy'. 
After searching for a solution on various sites, it seemed to be a problem caused by the network-manager, which didn't bring up the network-interface fast enough to allow mumble opening its socket.

Therefore i removed the network-manager from the boot sequence:
`update-rc.d network-manager remove`
and configured my network interface via the `/etc/interfaces`- and the `/etc/resolv.conf`-file as described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration).

Adding the network-manager as dependencie in the mumble-server init script `/etc/init.d/mumble-server` and doing `update-rc.d mumble-server remove && update-rc.d mumbleserver defaults`unfortunately didn't work out, although mumble received a higher sequence-value (19; network-manager had 18).